# How can I use for loop to iterate words/ combinations from "HTML" file?

Tags: python, for-loop, passwords, combinations

I'm trying to use For-loop through HTML file extension that contains a list of combinations, the idea is that when the for loop find the right combination it will then print the combination and break.

I already did it with a simple nested for loop and with pickle file extension and with text file, but I just can't make it work with HTML extension file.

The HTML does contain a "list" of the combination but the for loop doesn't recognize the combination from it. it seems to me that all of the combinations are printed as one big string.

please help.

Here is the code I used to create the HTML file:

```
list1 = []
def list1_default():
    for x1 in rangex:
        for x2 in rangex:
            guess = x1 + x2
            list1.append(guess)

    print(list1)
    with open("output2.html", "w") as file:
            file.write(str(list1))
```

and here is the main code to run the list and the combination equation

```
password = 10
def html_list_loop():
    htmlist = open('output2.html', 'r')
    for x in htmlist:
        guess = x
        print(guess)
        if password == guess:
            print(f"your password is {guess}")
            return
html_list_loop()
```

that's the **output that I get:**

```
['00', '01', '10', '11']
```

I expected the output to be: **(the output that I want to get)**

```
00
01
10
your password is 10
```

please help me to fix my code
thanks.

PS - if you know of better (faster) way/ file extension that can load list of possible combinations through a for loop, please share too.

Answer (score 0):

You have saved the list as a string. Unlike pickle, a text file like the one you wrote with the html extension will not convert this back to list format when reading. You can do so with [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
import ast

password = 10
def html_list_loop():
    htmlist = open('output2.html', 'r')
    for x in ast.literal_eval(htmlist.read()):
        guess = x
        print(guess)
        if password == guess:
            print(f"your password is {guess}")
            return
html_list_loop()
```

This will print:

```
0
1
10
your password is 10
```

---

An alternative approach with `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

list1 = [0, 1, 10, 11] # test list1
df = pd.DataFrame(list1, columns=['numbers']) # load as dataframe with column name 'numbers'
df.to_pickle('test.pkl') # store as pkl, other formats are possible, see https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/io.html
```

Then load and process the file:

```
password = 10
df = pd.read_pickle('test.pkl') #read file
hit = df[df['numbers'] == password] #filter by password
if not hit.empty: #if there are matches
    print(f'your password is {hit.iloc[0]["numbers"]}, found at index nr {hit.index.values[0]}') #print the number and index of the first match
```

Output:

```
your password is 10, found at index nr 2
```

Comment: thank you Adriaansen!  however, is there a faster way to load it? when there are 111111110 items in the list, it takes pretty long till it opens the file in python. (more than 200 sec),  compare to pickle or text which take only 20 sec.  what is the best / fastest way to run a giant list combinations?

Comment: I'd suggest a different approach to the project: load `list1` as a pandas dataframe, store it in [pickle](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_pickle.html) or another format. Load it and find matching queries by filtering the dataframe. This leverages a vectorized approach and will speed things up significantly. In any case don't store a huge list as a string.

Comment: could you please show me how to do that in a code? much appreciated! maybe through https://www.online-python.com/ or somewhere else, maybe here if possible, you probably know better than me.

Comment: Sure, I have updated the answer with an example

Comment: hey adrian, if I understand the code correctly, it acts like it knows what's the password in the first place.
the idea is that I want to crack the password in my .rar file eventually, and the code can't know the password without running all the combinations through the ".rar".
can you adjust the code that it will run through all combinations till match?

Comment: I suggest posting this as a new question, as your original question has been solved.